# How should i resolve this ClassCastException?

Tags: java

getting ClassCastException when i am adding a vertex to a linked list when doing BFS. Need help
Information: Vertex is a user defined class which has a linked list of Edge class objects.

here is my code:

```
private void reachable() {
        clearAll();

        for (Vertex v : vertexMap.values())
            v.setColor("white");

        for (Vertex s : vertexMap.values())
            if (s.isStatus())
                bfs(s);
    }

    private void bfs(Vertex s) {

        s.setColor("gray");
        s.dist = 0;
        s.prev = null;

        Queue<Vertex> vertices = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
        vertices.add(s);

        while (!vertices.isEmpty()) {
            Vertex u = vertices.remove();
            for (Iterator i = u.adjacent.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                Edge edge = (Edge) i.next();
                Vertex adj = edge.getDestVertex();
                if (!adj.getName().equals(u.getName()) && adj.isStatus())
                    if (adj.getColor().equals("white")) {
                        adj.setColor("gray");
                        adj.dist = u.dist + 1;
                        adj.prev = u;
                        vertices.add(adj);
                    }
            }
            u.setColor("black");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Posting the exception with full stacktrace would not be a bad idea.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: project2.Vertex cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Comment: There is no cast to `java.lang.Comparable` in the above code. Please add the full stack trace in the question (not as a comment!)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the problem is here:

```
    Queue<Vertex> vertices = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
    vertices.add(s);  // <<<---- HERE
```

A `PriorityQueue` needs to be able to compare instances of the parameter type (i.e. `Vertex`) to determine their relative priority.  If you instantiate the queue with a `Comparator<Vertex>` object as a parameter, then the queue will use that to determine the priority.  Otherwise, it expects `Vertex` to implement `Comparable<Vertex>`.

The exception is occurring because inside the `add` operation, the code is trying to cast `Vertex` objects to `Comparable`.

Solutions:

1. Declare the class as `... class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex>` and provide an implementation of the `int compareTo(Vertex)` method.
2. Implement a `Comparator<Vertex>` class with an implementation of `int compare(Vertex, Vertex)` and pass an instance to the `PriorityQueue` constructor.  (You could use an anonymous class.)

Either way, the compare / compareTo method is the basis for the queue's prioritization.  Implement it accordingly.